# Using the vue-konva with nuxtjs fails with various error

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, konvajs, konva, vue-konva

I followed the [documentation](https://konvajs.org/docs/vue/index.html) and [Github](https://github.com/konvajs/vue-konva/issues/18) I did the following steps:

1. install vue-konva and konva and canvas using `npm install vue-konva konva --save` and `npm install canvas --save`.
2. Created `vuekonva.js` under `plugins` folder with below content:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueKonva from 'vue-konva'
Vue.use(VueKonva)
```

3. Added `plugins: [ "~/plugins/vuekonva"],` under `nuxt.config.js`
4. I tried adding under `nuxt-config.js` but still no luck:

```
build: {
    standalone: true
  },
```

5. Created a page under `pages` folder and added code from documenation:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-stage ref="stage" :config="stageSize">
      <v-layer>
        <v-text :config="{ text: 'Some text on canvas', fontSize: 15 }" />
        <v-rect
          :config="{
            x: 20,
            y: 50,
            width: 100,
            height: 100,
            fill: 'red',
            shadowBlur: 10,
          }"
        />
        <v-circle
          :config="{
            x: 200,
            y: 100,
            radius: 50,
            fill: 'green',
          }"
        />
        <v-line
          :config="{
            x: 20,
            y: 200,
            points: [0, 0, 100, 0, 100, 100],
            tension: 0.5,
            closed: true,
            stroke: 'black',
            fillLinearGradientStartPoint: { x: -50, y: -50 },
            fillLinearGradientEndPoint: { x: 50, y: 50 },
            fillLinearGradientColorStops: [0, 'red', 1, 'yellow'],
          }"
        />
      </v-layer>
      <v-layer ref="dragLayer" />
    </v-stage>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      stageSize: {
        width,
        height
      }
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    if (process.browser) {
      this.stageSize.width = window.innerWidth
      this.stageSize.height = window.innerHeight
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

I get the error:
`Must use import to load ES Module:`

I tried without plugins and it is throwing the error:

```
vue.runtime.esm.js:620 [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <v-stage> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

found in
```

Not understanding whats the issue please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Nuxt documentation](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/directory-structure/plugins#es6-plugins) some plugins export an ES6 module. I think this is the case for **konva** node module. I followed the steps you mentioned above. But in the `nuxt.config.js` file I configured the plugin as follow:

```js
plugins: [    
    { src: "~/plugins/vuekonva", mode: 'client' }
],

build: {
    transpile: ['konva']
},
```

After that I replaced the code of your page with the code of [konvajs](https://konvajs.org/docs/vue/index.html) as follows:

```html
<template>
  <v-stage :config="configKonva">
    <v-layer>
      <v-circle :config="configCircle"></v-circle>
    </v-layer>
  </v-stage>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      configKonva: {
        width: 200,
        height: 200
      },
      configCircle: {
        x: 100,
        y: 100,
        radius: 70,
        fill: "red",
        stroke: "black",
        strokeWidth: 4
      }
    };
  }
};

</script>
```

That is working for me when I link to the page with `nuxt-link`. but if I refresh the page I get some errors that is maybe for SSR. I am not sure but if you read [this documentation](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/concepts/server-side-rendering/) you maybe could solve the problem for SSR.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. I have been trying various things with no luck. This helped me a lot. Thanks again. Have a great day

Comment: I think the problem you encountered is because the GitHub page is quite old. I also noticed that you used ```process.browser``` in your code that I think was [deprecated](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/4106) and must be replaced with ```process.client```.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification. Now, everything seems to work so started with my actual implementation.

Comment: You should use `mode: 'client'` rather than `ssr: false` here because of a deprecation too.

Comment: @kissu Thanks for the response. Changed based on your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

based in the nuxt documentacion
only create /plugings/konva-vue.client.js
and add this code  https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/plugins

```
import { defineNuxtPlugin } from '#app'
import  VueKonva from 'vue-konva'

export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
  nuxtApp.vueApp.use(VueKonva ) })
```

Comment: Your code is for Nuxt 3, but by the date of the question and the accepted answer, they clearly refer to Nuxt 2.